# Simple machine learning for website classification

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, cross-validation, text-classification

I am trying to generate a Python program that determines if a website is harmful (porn etc.).

First, I made a Python web scraping program that counts the number of occurrences for each word.

[result for harmful websites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE0xr.png)

It's a key value dictionary like

{ word : [ # occurrences in harmful websites, # of websites that contain these words] }.

Now I want my program to analyze the words from any websites to check if the website is safe or not. But I don't know which methods will suit to my data.

Comment: My idea was that if a website contains certain words ( a certain number of times) that are frequently appeared only on the harmful websites -> the website is harmful. Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: If you request for methods and tools to deal  with your data: learning and classifying. 
You could have look at [TensorFlow library](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started) and check [moocs](https://www.mooc-list.com/course/applied-machine-learning-python-coursera)

Comment: Scikit-learn may be more straightforward to start with. Work through a tutorial.

Comment: @SeanHwang ,Lets get serious here.I would request you revise your question a little bit and post it here in these two communities [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) and [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing here is your training data. You need some sort of [supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) technique where your training data consists of website's data itself (text document) and its label (`harmful` or `safe`).

You can certainly use the [RNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network) but there also other [natural language processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) techniques and much faster ones.

Typically, you should use a proper vectorizer on your training data (think of each site page as a text document), for example [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) (but also other possibilities; if you use Python I would strongly suggest [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) that provides lots of useful machine learning techniques and mentioned [sklearn.TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) is already within). The point is to vectorize your text document in enhanced way. Imagine for example the English word `the` how many times it typically exists in text? You need to think of biases such as these.

Once your training data is vectorized you can use for example [stochastic gradient descent](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html) classifier and see how it performs on your test data (in machine learning terminology the test data means to simply take some new data example and test what your ML program outputs).

In either case you will need to experiment with above options. There are many nuances and you need to test your data and see where you achieve the best results (depending on ML algorithm settings, type of vectorizer, used ML technique itself and so on). For example [Support Vector Machines](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) are great choice when it comes to binary classifiers too. You may wanna play with that too and see if it performs better than SGD.

In any case, remember that you will need to obtain quality training data with labels (`harmful` vs. `safe`) and find the best fitting classifier. On your journey to find the best one you may also wanna use [cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) to determine how well your classifier behaves. Again, already contained in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).

*N.B. Don't forget about valid cases. For example there may be a completely safe online magazine where it only mentions the harmful topic in some article; it doesn't mean the website itself is harmful though.*

Edit: As I think of it, if you don't have any experience with ML at all it could be useful to take any [online course](https://www.google.cz/search?q=machine%20learning%20course) because despite the knowledge of API and libraries you will still need to know what it does and the math behind the curtain (at least roughly).

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called sentiment classification and is usually done with recurrent neural networks (RNNs) or Long short-term memory networks (LSTMs). This is not an easy topic to start with machine learning. If you are new you should have a look into linear/logistic regression, SVMs and basic neural networks (MLPs) first. Otherwise it will be hard to understand what is going on.

That said: there are many libraries out there for constructing neural networks. Probably easiest to use is `keras`. While this library simplifies a lot of things immensely, it isn't just a magic box that makes gold from trash. You need to understand what happens under the hood to get good results. [Here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py) is an example of how you can perform sentiment classification on the IMDB dataset (basically determine whether a movie review is positive or not) with `keras`.

Comment: Are you sure about this ?

Comment: Sure about what?

Answer (score 0):

For people who have no experience in NLP or ML, I recommend using [TFIDF vectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) instead of using deep learning libraries. In short, it converts sentences to vector, taking each word in vocabulary to one dimension (degree is occurrence).

Then, you can calculate [cosine similarity](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html) to resulting vector.

To improve performance, use [stemming / lemmatizing / stopwords](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html) supported in NLTK libraires.